# Get the value of sys.argv[1] and concatenate it with some string literals

Tags: python

I simply want to get the value of sys.argv[1] and concatenate it with some string literals.

This is my script:

```
import sys

myValue = sys.argv[1]
out = 'a' + myValue + 'c'
print (out)
```

When i run the python script with the parameter "b", i expect to get:
"abc"

But i am getting:
"cb"

Anyone know why?

Comment: Your script works fine for me. I get `abc` as the output.

Comment: Ya . Your code is fine . I have not found any error. For me also getting the output `abc`

Comment: It's acting like the value in `sys.argv[1]` is actually `"b\r"` - `ab` gets output, the carriage return goes back to the start of the line, the `c` overwrites the `a`.  I have no idea how you managed to unintentionally get a carriage return into a parameter, however.

Comment: Thanks a lot jasonharper, this is exactly the problem "\r".

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Loocid that I don't see a problem with your code as-is.

```
//string_literal.py
import sys

myValue = sys.argv[1]
out = 'a' + myValue + 'c'
print (out)
```

And I run it:

```
//sh
$ python string_literal.py 0
>>a0c
```

This indicates to me that you are having a problem that is outside of what you showed us. Anyway, to the other part of your question about working with string literals, I would recommend to you `.format`. With format you create what other languages (and I guess python) would call a "string template"

```
//string_template.py
import sys

print("a{}c".format(sys.argv[1]))
```

And I run it with the same result:

```
//sh
$ python string_template.py 0
>>a0c
```

Comment: Thanks all, i think i've found the problem.

Comment: By printing sys.argv, i can see the sys.argv[1] has a trailing "\r", I will remove it. Thanks again guys!!